# In php can we use session anywhere in php project?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I create `$_SESSION['id']` in index.php, i tried to access `$_SESSION['id']` in folder1/page1.php but I can't access session id.

How to access my session id.This is the notice I got
 
`Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs......`.

Comment: Every entry point to the page/app (every .php file the user can access directly) needs to start with `session_start();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use session variable in php than in all file you can session_start () is used in php script